# Where is my error when trying to display this graph with Chart.js?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, chart.js

Within my Laravel project I am implementing the chart.js library trying to visualize a bar graph.

**Which should show all work orders in finished status that were assigned to users with the operator role.**

When you want to graph, simply **no data is displayed, it is an empty graph.**

[image: grafico]

This is my ReportController controller **with this method public function getChart () I do my query**

```
public function getChart(Request $request)
    {      
        $_orders = DB::table('users')
            ->join('orders','orders.user_id','=','users.id')
            ->join('model_has_roles', 'users.id', '=', 'model_has_roles.model_id')                        
            ->select('users.id','users.name', DB::raw('COUNT(orders.id) as orders_by_user'), 'model_has_roles.role_id as rol')                   
            ->where('model_has_roles.role_id', '2');
        $_orders->groupBy('orders.user_id', 'users.id',  'users.name',  'model_has_roles.role_id');
        $orders=$_orders->get();

        return ['orders' => $orders];

    }
```

**This is the result of my query: as it is observed I have what I need username and the number of orders completed per user.**

```
{
"orders": [
{
"id": 4,
"name": "Luis",
"orders_by_user": 2,
"rol": 2
},
{
"id": 6,
"name": "Jose",
"orders_by_user": 1,
"rol": 2
},
{
"id": 7,
"name": "Miguel",
"orders_by_user": 1,
"rol": 2
}
]
}
```

**Here is an important question: is the JSON structure returned by my query correct? With this result can I graph?**

This is my report.js file for the graph:

**With the renderChart() method:
I make the graph, through the data obtained in my ajax call.**

**With the getChartData () method:
I make my ajax call.**

```
function renderChart(data, labels) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("orders").getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'ordenes',
                data: data,
                borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                borderWidth: 1,
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true                        
                    }
                }]
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: "Ordenes en estado terminado"
            },
        }
    });
}

function getChartData() {   

    $.ajax({
        url: '/admin/reports/getChart',
        type: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

           // console.log(data);
            var data = [];
            var labels = [];

            for (var i in data) {
                data.push(data[i].orders_by_user);
                labels.push(data[i].name);

            }

            renderChart(data, labels);
        },
        error: function (data) {

            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}

$("#renderBtn").click(
    function () {
        getChartData();
    }
);
```

**In other words I am looking to optimize my query using eloquent, so that it returns a valid JSON response for chart.js.
Dump those data obtained through an ajax call and draw**

Could you help me find and solve my error?

**UPDATED 1**

Just in case if any error arises change my for: `for (var i in data)` to this: `for (var i in response)`

So it looks like this:

```
 for (var i in response) {

     data.push(response[i].orders_by_user);
     labels.push(response[i].name);

 }
```

I think that I am not accessing correctly the data that I get from my query to later graph.
In the console I see the following information:

```
{orders: Array(3)}
orders: Array(3)
0: {id: 4, name: "Luis", orders_by_user: 2, rol: 2}
1: {id: 6, name: "Jose", orders_by_user: 1, rol: 2}
2: {id: 7, name: "Miguel", orders_by_user: 1, rol: 2}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

**Orders is my array, so how can I just access orders_by_user and name and correctly pass it to my data.push and labels.push**

try something like this but it doesn't work:

```
data.push(response[i].orders.orders_by_user);
labels.push(response[i].orders.name);
```

Comment: No javascript expert, but doesn't `var data = [];` "reset" `data` to an empty array, thus "emptying" the `data` you return from your ajax call? Maybe give `var data = [];` a different name?

Comment: @kerbholz I understand what you told me so I changed the for "data" to "response" and kept the above, I still cannot graph.
**Please note my update I have made the changes, what can you suggest me?**

Comment: Something like `for (var i in response.orders) {` maybe? You want to loop over the `orders` array data, not your response. And it should be `data.push(response.orders[i].orders_by_user);`. But no JS expert here ;) Or: you could edit your PHP to just return the results you need

Comment: @kerbholz great, thanks I suspected I was not accessing my array correctly.
On the other hand, the ideal would be to perform my eloquent query and return a response with a correct JSON structure.
**Could you guide me to build the query with eloquent?**